# Why there are many GNOME packges even after removing GNOME?

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, desktop-environment

I have 2 desktop manager Xfce and Gnome, I liked Xfce
,Additional I was short on storage, So I decided to delete Gnome with this command `apt purge --autoremove kali-desktop-gnome`. But when I run the command `dpkg -l | grep gnome`, it outputs many packages associated with Gnome. How to delete/remove those? They're useless packages, Do I have to delete/remove each of one-by-one manually Or is there any other command?

Output of `dpkg -l | grep gnome`

```
ii  chrome-gnome-shell                       10.1-5                          all          GNOME Shell extensions integration for web browsers
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64          3.34.3-2                        amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:amd64            3.38.3-1                        amd64        Introspection data for GnomeDesktop
ii  gkbd-capplet                             3.26.1-1                        amd64        GNOME control center tools for libgnomekbd
ii  gnome-accessibility-themes               3.28-1                          all          High Contrast GTK+ 2 theme and icons
ii  gnome-backgrounds                        3.38.0-1                        all          Set of backgrounds packaged with the GNOME desktop
ii  gnome-bluetooth                          3.34.3-2                        amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  gnome-brave-icon-theme                   5.5.1-2.1                       all          blue variation of the GNOME-Colors icon theme
ii  gnome-calculator                         3.38.2-1                        amd64        GNOME desktop calculator
ii  gnome-characters                         3.34.0-1                        amd64        character map application
ii  gnome-colors-common                      5.5.1-2.1                       all          common icons for all GNOME-Colors icon themes
ii  gnome-contacts                           3.38.1-1+b1                     amd64        Contacts manager for GNOME
ii  gnome-control-center                     1:3.38.3-1                      amd64        utilities to configure the GNOME desktop
ii  gnome-control-center-data                1:3.38.3-1                      all          configuration applets for GNOME - data files
ii  gnome-desktop3-data                      3.38.3-1                        all          Common files for GNOME desktop apps
ii  gnome-disk-utility                       3.38.1-1                        amd64        manage and configure disk drives and media
ii  gnome-font-viewer                        3.34.0-2+b1                     amd64        font viewer for GNOME
ii  gnome-icon-theme                         3.12.0-3                        all          GNOME Desktop icon theme
ii  gnome-keyring                            3.36.0-1                        amd64        GNOME keyring services (daemon and tools)
ii  gnome-keyring-pkcs11:amd64               3.36.0-1                        amd64        GNOME keyring module for the PKCS#11 module loading library
ii  gnome-logs                               3.36.0-2                        amd64        viewer for the systemd journal
ii  gnome-menus                              3.36.0-1                        amd64        GNOME implementation of the freedesktop menu specification
ii  gnome-online-accounts                    3.38.0-3                        amd64        service to manage online accounts for the GNOME desktop
ii  gnome-online-miners                      3.34.0-2                        amd64        Crawls through your online content
ii  gnome-orca                               3.38.2-1                        all          Scriptable screen reader - transitional package
ii  gnome-session                            3.38.0-3                        all          GNOME Session Manager - GNOME 3 session
ii  gnome-session-bin                        3.38.0-3                        amd64        GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
ii  gnome-session-canberra                   0.30-7                          amd64        GNOME session log in and log out sound events
ii  gnome-session-common                     3.38.0-3                        all          GNOME Session Manager - common files
ii  gnome-settings-daemon                    3.38.1-3                        amd64        daemon handling the GNOME session settings
ii  gnome-settings-daemon-common             3.38.1-3                        all          daemon handling the GNOME session settings - common files
ii  gnome-shell                              3.38.3-2                        amd64        graphical shell for the GNOME desktop
ii  gnome-shell-common                       3.38.3-2                        all          common files for the GNOME graphical shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock         69-1                            all          dash-to-dock extension for GNOME shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons      20.04.0+git20200908-5           all          desktop icon support for GNOME Shell
ii  gnome-shell-extension-prefs              3.38.3-2                        amd64        tool to enable / disable GNOME Shell extensions
ii  gnome-shell-extension-proxyswitcher      1.2-0kali9                      all          menu for the GNOME Shell to switch the proxy mode
ii  gnome-shell-extension-workspaces-to-dock 54-0kali1                       all          additional options for GNOME workspace switcher
ii  gnome-shell-extensions                   3.38.2-1kali1                   all          Extensions to extend functionality of GNOME Shell
ii  gnome-software                           3.38.0-3                        amd64        Software Center for GNOME
ii  gnome-software-common                    3.38.0-3                        all          Software Center for GNOME (common files)
ii  gnome-sushi                              3.38.0-1                        amd64        sushi is a quick previewer for nautilus
ii  gnome-system-monitor                     3.38.0-1                        amd64        Process viewer and system resource monitor for GNOME
ii  gnome-terminal                           3.38.2-1kali1                   amd64        GNOME terminal emulator application
ii  gnome-terminal-data                      3.38.2-1kali1                   all          Data files for the GNOME terminal emulator
ii  gnome-theme-kali                         2021.1.3                        all          Transitional package to install kali-themes
ii  gnome-themes-extra:amd64                 3.28-1                          amd64        Adwaita GTK+ 2 theme — engine
ii  gnome-themes-extra-data                  3.28-1                          all          Adwaita GTK+ 2 theme — common files
ii  gnome-tweak-tool                         3.34.0-4                        all          adjust advanced settings for GNOME - transitional package
ii  gnome-tweaks                             3.34.0-4                        all          tool to adjust advanced configuration settings for GNOME
ii  gnome-user-docs                          3.38.2-1                        all          GNOME user docs
ii  gnome-user-share                         3.34.0-2                        amd64        User level public file sharing via WebDAV
ii  libgnome-autoar-0-0:amd64                0.2.4-2                         amd64        Archives integration support for GNOME
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64               3.34.3-2                        amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64              3.38.3-1                        amd64        Utility library for loading .desktop files - runtime files
ii  libgnome-menu-3-0:amd64                  3.36.0-1                        amd64        GNOME implementation of the freedesktop menu specification
ii  libgnomekbd-common                       3.26.1-1                        all          GNOME library to manage keyboard configuration - common files
ii  libgnomekbd8:amd64                       3.26.1-1                        amd64        GNOME library to manage keyboard configuration - shared library
ii  libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64               3.36.0-1                        amd64        PAM module to unlock the GNOME keyring upon login
ii  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:amd64                 2.72.0-2                        amd64        HTTP l
ii  nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal        3.38.2-1kali1                   amd64        GNOME 
ii  network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome        1.2.8-2+b2                      amd64        networ
ii  network-manager-gnome                    1.20.0-1                        amd64        networ
ii  network-manager-l2tp-gnome               1.2.18-1+b2                     amd64        networ
ii  network-manager-openconnect-gnome        1.2.6-1                         amd64        networ
ii  network-manager-openvpn-gnome            1.8.12-2                        amd64        networ
ii  network-manager-pptp-gnome               1.2.8-3+b2                      amd64        networ
ii  network-manager-vpnc-gnome               1.2.6-3                         amd64        networ
ii  pinentry-gnome3                          1.1.0-4                         amd64        GNOME 
ii  policykit-1-gnome                        0.105-7                         amd64        authen
```

After, I even run the command `dpkg -l | grep gnome` again. But it returned gnome is not installed, How do I completely delete/remove all packages related to Gnome.

Output of `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove kali-desktop-gnome`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'kali-desktop-gnome' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 712 not upgraded.
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge '.*gnome.*'` with or without `--auto-remove`

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov   `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove                         
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 712 not upgraded.`  Should I go for purge command  `sudo apt-get purge '.*gnome.*' `

Comment: The command didn't work, hm, let me check again.

Comment: Try `'*gnome*'` instead if your distro/apt is fresh enough. I'm not following Ubuntu or its derivatives.

Comment: This command should work:

`sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/gnome/{print $2}')`

Comment: `Building dependency tree.. Done
Reading state information.. Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/gnome/{print $2}') ` the output for this command is in the above command it showing error

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov. I redirected the output of `dpkg -l | grep gnome >> file.txt`. formatted to the file to hold only the package name and deleting the rest. then copied every package into terminal and run `apt purge [package1] [package 2]` . cleared everything. Anyways thanks for the Help :)

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove kali-desktop-gnome` You actually removed `desktop-gnome`(Your "window" or whatever it's called I don't remember). You didn't remove `gnome`. That's why you have all other things